# Slowy fade in or load an image from left to right with post-load delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, header

I have an image of a vine of leaves I'd like to load slowly from left to right after a delay (after the site fully loads) to underline and emphasize a slogan of website I'm working on.  I don't want to animate the image, just make it seem as though it is growing by loading it slowly.

Is there a CSS solution or would it be easier to use Jquery?

Thanks so much in advance for any help!

Comment: Please explain what you mean with "growing" and "loading it slowly".

Comment: I just want an image to animate into existence in a very specific way.  It's a line ------------ and around that line is a vine.  I want the line to load over time and then the vine to load over time on top of that to create the effect or feel of vines growing.  Nothing too fancy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a CSS solution to your query. In photoshop you can save a jpeg or png as progressive (interlaced) so that it downloads progressively but on anything but the slowest link a regular size file will appear to load quickly.

I would have thought your easiest option was an animated gif - the opacity and apparent size could be tightly controlled and you can set it only to run once per visit. You could bind the image to the jQuery(document).ready() callback for the "after the site fully loads" part of your request.

Comment: Ofcourse!  Very simple solution.  Any suggestions on how to build the gif?

Comment: I work in photoshop for animated gifs so: window->animation will give you the animation panel. There is a tutorial here: [link](http://psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tutorials-effects/how-to-animate-a-gif-inside-of-photoshop-cs4/)